# Set number of search results on paper-autocomplete without scrollbar

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

How do I increase the number of search results displayed on paper-autocomplete control without scroll bar. By default I am getting 7 items, but I would like to increase the count and get rid of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean this [paper-autocomplete](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete) library. The library already prepare an attribute for that which is [maxViewableItems](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete/elements/paper-autocomplete-suggestions#property-maxViewableItems).

You can set it on `paper-autocomplete-suggestions` element like:

```
<paper-autocomplete-suggestions
  max-viewable-items='15'>
</paper-autocomplete-suggestions>
```

Plunker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RYbTHkFfQOeUaP366XGS?p=preview)

If you mean another library, let me know I will update my answer again.

Comment: Yeah I thought there could be some way of doing this without the suggestions control. Looks like this is only way to go.